# How to calculate phone call length in 6 second increments

Tags: time, ivr

We log phone calls to our SQL server and to calculate billing we need to calculate in 6 second increments where they pay for all full or partial 6 second increments of time in the call.

We have the call length as a number in seconds, and we can do the work using a case statement to calculate it. I am looking for a more time / clock cycle efficient way to do this.

Has anyone else already done this and has a query they would be willing to share?

Examples:

Call is 30 seconds in length, since 30 is divisible by 6 (no remainder) we bill for 30 seconds.
Call is 0 seconds in length. No bill.
Call is 32 seconds in length, 32 is not divisible by 6 so bill for 36 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

You should bill for 6*ceil(time/6.0) seconds.